# email in iphone appears as jibberish

Tags: iphone, encoding, character-encoding, email, phpmailer

i'm using phpmailer to send myself notifications on email.
the email is in html and the body contains hebrew characters.

on my mac the email looks fine but on the iphone it appears as jibberish.

i tried every possible combination of encoding header both on the html head tag and as a property of the phpmailer but no luck.

any ideas?

thanks

how do i format the code??

require("./classes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mailer->Username = 'bla@gmail.com';  // Change this to your gmail adress
$mailer->Password = '1234';  // Change this to your gmail password
$mailer->From = 'joe@gmail.com';  // This HAVE TO be your gmail adress
$mailer->FromName = 'Mail'; // This is the from name in the email, you   can put anything you like here
$mailer->IsHTML(true);
$mailer->Body = $message;
$mailer->Subject = $subject;

$mailer->AddAddress('me@gmail.com');  // This is where you put the email   adress of the person you want to mail
if ($mailer->Send()) echo "ok";
else echo "no ok";

Comment: Best to post the code you're using with phpmailer.

Comment: Use <code> and </code> to wrap your code. Also maybe add in new lines, it's a bit hard to read this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure your email is being sent as UTF-8 with the proper headers and meta tags for best results when sending unicode email. If you don't explicitly specify that you are sending UTF-8, intermediary and receiving mail servers are free to make assumptions about the character set and encoding of the message.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a validation on top of your script that will check the client browser/OS, if OS=iphone then optimise your $message in an iphone-friendly format.